# hook_menu - setting a variable to use in page.tpl.php

Tags: routes

I know how to use `hook_preprocess_page()` to add/change variables for use in page.tpl.php. For nodes, you can use `menu_get_object()` to load the current node and process it from there.

How do I do this for a page I've created using `hook_menu()`? I've tried printing out all the $variables but there is nothing much I can identify this page with, apart from the 'theme_suggestions' which seems a bit flaky. Using `arg(0)` also seems like a hacky way to go.

Is there any way to set the page.tpl.php variable directly with `hook_menu()`? That would be ideal.

**EDIT for clarification:**

This is what I want to achieve:

```
function mymodule_menu() {

  $items['my-page'] = array(
    'title' => t('My Page'),
    'page callback' => 'mymodule_callback',
    'access callback' => TRUE,
    'page arguments' => array(),
    'page vars' => array('myvariable' => 'hello') // Obviously this doesn't work, but would be great
  );

}

function mymodule_preprocess_page(&$vars) {

  if($something === 'my-page'){ // What to do here???
     $vars['myvariable'] = 'hello';
  }

}
```

Basically I want something within hook_preprocess_page &$vars array to identify the route I have created with hook_menu. If I can define this somehow in hook_menu itself (or the callback) it would be even better.

I can use arg(0) but that doesn't account for any subpages, and I might want to change the route which means I need to change preprocess function too. Is there a better way?

Comment: hook_menu() simply creates a path on your system. It has no direct relationship to the template that outputs that path. Can you edit your question and give a specific example of what you want to happen, rather than talking in generalities? It would make it easier to understand your goal.

Comment: I agree with @Jaypan. The answer to your question as it is now is _no_, but that is not much helpful to you. If you edit your question to make it more specific to what you are trying to achieve, it will get a more helpful answer, for you and for future users.

Answer (score 0):

Just as an option, you could use a specific page template for your path, and sub-paths.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_preprocess_page
**/
function HOOK_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
  // Optional logic to check path condition
  // e.g arg(), request_uri(), current_path() etc..
  $some_condition = FALSE;
  if(arg(0) == 'base' || $some_condition) {
    // Set single page--base.tpl.php template, for /base and /base/subpath
    // Note: this overrides theme_hook_suggestions[]
    $variables['theme_hook_suggestion'] = 'page__base';
    // Sample template variable
    $variables['foo'] = 'bar';
  }

}
```

Then, in your theme, you can copy `page.tpl.php` to `page--base.tpl.php` and add whatever page specific markup you need in the template.

You could also add logic and template variables to `hook_preprocess_page`.  They would be available in your custom template. They can also be added there for the default `page.tpl.php` template. In any case, you will need some condition check for the specific target path match there.

Some relevant API functions to check the URL path include:

- [`arg`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21bootstrap.inc/function/arg/7.x)
- [`current_path`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21path.inc/function/current_path/7.x)
- [`request_uri`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21bootstrap.inc/function/request_uri/7.x)

Note: `arg()` is also used by core [`template_preprocess_page`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21theme.inc/function/template_preprocess_page/7.x) to set the theme suggestions.

> Uses the arg() function to generate a series of page template suggestions based on the current path.